# Trying to get java servlets doGet method to bring browser to correct page

Tags: java, servlets

[Here is the web xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwS5m.png)

I'm trying to get the links to bring the browser to the jsp (ex: BookForm.jsp, BookList.jsp) but when the links are clicked their brought to

- localhost:8080/Bookstore/list
- localhost:8080/bookstore/insert
- localhost:8080/Bookstore/update

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getServletPath();
        System.out.println(action);
        try {
            switch (action) {
            case "/list":
                listBook(request, response);
                break;
            case "/new":
                showNewForm(request, response);
                break;
            case "/insert":
                insertBook(request, response);
                break;
            case "/delete":
                deleteBook(request, response);
                break;
            case "/edit":
                showEditForm(request, response);
                break;
            case "/update":
                updateBook(request, response);
                break;
            default:
                listBook(request, response);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
    }
    private void listBook(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {
        List<Book> listBook = bookDAO.listAllBooks();
        request.setAttribute("listBook", listBook);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("BookList.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
 
    private void showNewForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("BookForm.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
 
    private void showEditForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws SQLException, ServletException, IOException {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Book existingBook = bookDAO.getBook(id);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("BookForm.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("book", existingBook);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
 
    }
```

Comment: Are you on Tomcat? Why not have the user click the link to the JSP directly? Why route via a servlet?

Comment: Can you show us your entire class as well as your web.xml?

Comment: I edited the post to add a ss of the web xml and the class is too long to post it all. I'm following this tutorial [link] (https://www.codejava.net/coding/jsp-servlet-jdbc-mysql-create-read-update-delete-crud-example)

Answer (score 0):

Check your web xml file for a correct servlet mapping.

Example code for java servlet mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.yourpath.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>milk</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/drink/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>points</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pointlist</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```